# Gravitational potential at instant of collision

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, symmetry, collision

Two spheres colliding that are gravitationally attracted. I want to understand what the gravitational potential between the two is at the point of collision. Is it negative or positive or zero?
This is not a homework question either I am merely trying to understand the relationship between gravitational potential energy and the gravitational attraction between two objects.

Comment: Hi Franz Liszt. Welcome to Phys.SE. Do you know Newton's shell theorem?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to understand what the gravitational potential between the two is at the point of collision. Is it negative or positive or zero?

The gravitational potential can be specified using any point as a reference. The potential will be zero at the reference point, positive further away, and negative closer. So you can choose the answer to your question simply by choosing your reference point appropriately.

However, by far the most common convention is to choose the reference “at infinity”. The collision clearly is closer than infinity. So with this convention the potential will be negative at the point of collision.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are asking to the gravitational potential difference between the two spheres.

You can use Newton's law of gravitation while they are still separated to find the gravitational force:

$$F_g=G\frac{mM}{r^2}.$$

Then divide this force with a mass and you have the gravitational *potential*. $r$ is the distance between their centres-of-mass. For ideal spheres, that points will for each of them be right in the middle, at their geometric centres.

If the spheres don't break at impact, then this is where the story ends. The gravitational potential can then at any moment be calculated as above.

But if they at impact break apart (like colliding planets, stars, galaxies and the like), then this law applies no more. Well, actually it does, but the centres-of-mass will be disturbed so that $r$ is unknown, plus there will be extra effects due to mass being rearranged to wildly to either side of both "spheres". In this case, you can't know anymore but will have to rely on emperical tests or the like. Of this reason, you will never reach the mathematical impossibility in formula above with a division by zero, since $r$ never becomes zero.

Answer (score 0):

We don't usually care about the potential. We care how it changes. So as long as the potential decreases as you get closer to the earth, it describes gravity. You can say the potential is 0 at the surface, and thus if you go below the earth the potential is negative, or you can make the potential when you are infinitely away from the earth to be 0. You can do whatever you want, as long as it decreases ~$-\frac{1}{r}$

The gravitational field ,i.e. gravitational acceleration or force per mass, is what is important and it is the derivative of the potential.